# Patterns for developing and merging teamcity build configurations

Tags: teamcity

During normal development of any coded or configured project usually involves merging changes of some sort.

The same holds true for TeamCity build configurations themselves.  Currently I'm failing to see a good way to do this in TeamCity.  So far I've found a couple of primary ways to move a developed build configuration to a production usage.

These assume you already have a build configuration in use for production... i.e. it's not being actively modified or configured.

1. Make a copy of the build configuration A.  We'll call the copy build configuration B.
2. Make your changes to configuration B and test them.

Now, there are two ways to get this back to the configuration A.

A.  Delete build configuration A and move configuration B in.

- doing this would remove any history of configuration A.

or

B.  Manually, by hand, make the changed needed to configuration A.

- This seems very error prone and lends itself to a great deal of human error.

If there is a better way to do this, or anybody has any thoughts, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to test your changes in isolation, especially when you use templates a lot and changing a template could affect a number of builds. In this scenario I normally detach the configuration from the template, make and test the changes. Then I reattach the configuration to the template and apply the changes at the template level. This then means I can then apply tested changes to DEV / TEST / UAT / etc configurations as they are all working off the same template.

TeamCity also has a really nice feature where you can sync your changes to your VCS - This mean that you can make changes in the UI or in code, and you have a history of your changes so you rollback edits to configurations quite easily.

I don't know if there's an optimum strategy, but the first option works for me, although I always have TeamCity write it's settings back to VCS where possible

Hope this may be of some help.

Comment: Thanks.  I know TC allows you to sync your changes to your vcs, but unfortunately my vcs isn't supported for this yet.

BTW, Perforce will be supported in 9.1.